# Polynomial/ Exponential diophantine equation

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am looking for the reference characterizing all the cases when 
$$an^2+bn+c=2^m$$
has infinitely many positive integer solutions (m,n). Thanks.

Comment: Which do you mean as the variables and which as the parameters?

Comment: i've added the clarification. Here, $a,b,c$ are fixed whereas $m,n$ vary

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation  First impression, solutions are finite unless $b=c=0$ and $a = 2^k$

Comment: Thanks Will! In case quadratic function is a complete square, we can have infinitely many solutions. But this together with your characterization covers all cases indeed. I think I will just cite Siegel work.

Comment: I see, like $n^2 + 2 n + 1$ or $2^k (n^2 + 2 wn + w^2)$ for fixed $w$

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

(Ax+B)(Cx+D)=ACx^2 +(AD+BC)x + BD = ax^2 +bx + c , we have

a=AC

b=AD+BC

c= BD

For any arbitrary value of A and  x there is a number like B so that:

B=2^m - Ax;   where m is an arbitrary number.

Similarly for any arbitrary value of C and x there is a number like D so that:

D=2^k - Cx;  where k is an arbitrary number.

Therefore There are infinitely many relations such as:

(Ax+B)(Cx+D)=2^m . 2^k = 2^(m+k) =2^n

That is the equation ax^2 +bx + c = 2^n has infinitely many solutions with above mentioned conditions. All factors and variable can be positive integers,